# PHP string remove space

Tags: php, string

Is there php function to remove the space inside the string? for example:

```
$abcd="this is a test"
```

I want to get the string:

```
$abcd="thisisatest"
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will also work

```
$abcd="this is a test";
$abcd = preg_replace('/( *)/', '', $abcd);
echo $abcd."\n"; //Will output 'thisisatest';
```

or

```
$abcd = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $abcd);
```

See manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: There is no need to use a regular expression if he only wants to replaces spaces. It can be useful to replace all "spacing" characters with the \s assertion though.

Comment: @savageman - str_replace is a better option to use, I posted this as an alternative.

Comment: Since nobody else said it, I'll go ahead and mention that str_replace is faster than preg_replace. That plus simplicity of use is why it's a preferred alternative. Did not know about \s so thanks for that.

Comment: @Syntax Error, yip str_replace is faster. Thx for mentioning it.

Comment: overkill. @Gordon's solution is better.

Answer (score 16):

```
$abcd = str_replace(' ', '', 'this is a test');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```